# How to get the latest version of git-core on debian lenny

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, repository, update

I'm trying to update my version of git that I'm using on the debian 5.0 lenny webserver (from 1.5 in the default package repository to at least 1.7 in the latest stable updates, according to the ubuntu ppa archives).

How would I add a repository to get a more stable version in Debian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1. Update your distro
2. See if [backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions) has the version you need and add `lenny-backports` to your `apt`
3. Get the s[ource package and rebuild it](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/20) on your server (or on a Lenny machine, wich is more safe)
4. Add squeeze repository to apt sources, then add the `APT::Default-Release` option to apt configuration and ask to install the new version. I will not describe that option in depth because I am very against it (and it will possibly break a lot of stuff) so only try that if you really want.

Comment: This, I found out just a bit ago, (should have refreshed) is true.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it, here:

http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Had to switch out "squeeze-backports" with "lenny-backports" before it would work, but it worked in the end, and got me up to version 1.7, so that's all I needed.